# Simple Ember + Ember Data + Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ember.js

I'm trying to use ember together with Rails, but getting an strange error.

It's a very simple nested route test.

I have a rails resource named "Post", just like the video on ember docs:

https://github.com/tildeio/bloggr-client  and I've got almost everything working.

```
http://domain.com/admin#/posts/ works fine
```

clicking on a post, shows me the details, change the url.

but when I try to load it directly:

```
http://domain.com/admin#/posts/1
```

The error happens.

This is my console output:

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember.js?body=1:382
DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.7 ember.js?body=1:382
DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0 ember.js?body=1:382
DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.10.2 ember.js?body=1:382
DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember.js?body=1:382
Assertion failed: Your model must not be anonymous. It was (subclass of App.Post)     ember.js?body=1:382
GET http://localhost:3000/post)s/1 404 (Not Found) jquery.js?body=1:8707
Error while loading route: 
Class {id: "1", store: Class, _reference: Object, currentState: Object, _changesToSync:     Object…}
 ember.js?body=1:382
Uncaught <(subclass of App.Post):ember269:1>
```

The strange thing is the url that ember is generating, http://domain.com/post)s/1

Where is this ) comming from?

This is my js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap_bootstrap
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require bootstrap-wysihtml5
//= require bootstrap-wysihtml5/locales/pt-BR
//= require handlebars
//= require ember
//= require ember-data
//= require_self

// for more details see: http://emberjs.com/guides/application/
App = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElement: '#ember_root'
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 12,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts', function() {
    this.resource('post', { path: ':post_id' });
  });
});

App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Post.find();
  }
});


var attr = DS.attr;

App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title: attr('string'),
  description: attr('string')
});

//= require_tree .
```

Edit.:

This is the Json that my app is consuming:

```
{"posts":[{"id":7,"title":"teste","description":"su o autor"}]}
```

My views:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
<div class="row">
  <div class="span9">
    {{outlet}}
  </div>
  <div class="span3">
    <div class="well sidebar-nav">
      <h3>Ember Sidebar</h3>
      <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
        <li>{{#linkTo 'posts'}}Posts{{/linkTo}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="posts">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
          <table class='table'>
            <thead>
              <tr><th>Recent Posts</th></tr>
            </thead>
            {{#each model}}
            <tr><td>
              {{#linkTo 'post' this}}{{title}}{{/linkTo}}
            </td></tr>
            {{/each}}
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="span9">
          {{outlet}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="posts/index">
  <p class="text-warning">Please select a post</p>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="post">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <h2>{{{description}}}</h2>
  <hr>
</script>
```

Comment: This is strange, your code is simple, but gives this error. Can you show your templates?

Comment: The error is coming from ember data's json serializer, it is trying to determine name of your model by calling toString() but getting (subclass of App.Post) instead of the expected "App.Post". That's also why the url looks crazy. Curious what your API response looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated to lastest versions and everything worked.